# Image supervised classification tool is unavailable

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.8

I want to perform image supervised classification but supervised classification tool is disabled. Other tools like unsupervised classification are available.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you created your training samples?  From the [help](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/image-classification/an-overview-of-the-image-classification-toolbar.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_022D05183A5946B0AAD6C59395097D59): "*There must be at least two training samples present for this option to be available.*".

Comment: Let me check....